# distinct date in where clause possible?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to get records for each distinct date in SQl Server 2005?

Example:

```
Select sum(AmountSold), Date from tableA where Distinct(Date)
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks in advance!!

Ramu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(AmountSold), Date 
FROM tableA
GROUP BY Date
```